# Is this a correct application of recursion? (displaying items of a stack)

Tags: c, function, recursion, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct node Node;


void display(Node *head);
void push(Node **top, int newvalue);

int main(){

    Node *topPtr = NULL;

    push (&topPtr, 123);     // test with 123

    display(topPtr);

}

void display(Node *head){
    if (head == NULL){
        printf("\n");
        return;
    } else {
        printf("\n%d", head->value);    //
        display(head->nextPtr);         // is this recursion?
    }
}

void push(Node **top, int newvalue){
    Node *newlinkPtr = calloc(1,sizeof(Node));

    if(newlinkPtr){
        newlinkPtr->value = newvalue;
        newlinkPtr->nextPtr = *top;
        *top = newlinkPtr;
    } else {
        printf("\nNo memory.\n");
    }
}
```

Is the `display()` function a correct recursion application? I have this doubt because usually I do the recursive call inside the printf, but not this time. Is it still a recursion? If it isn't is there a way to do everything inside the printf?

Comment: Yes, it's recursion. In fact it's a special form of recursion called ["tail recursion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a 'correct application of recursion'. As long as you're getting the result you want with reasonably use of computation and memory resources, any implementation should be fine.

For the specific case above, yes it looks like you've implemented recursion correctly and it will give you a result with reasonable time complexity.